# MySql insert into two tables connected with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, erd

I have two tables connected with table with two foreign keys (like on the picture below).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ruPi.png

In table menu I want to have name of pizza and her price.
In table item I want to have components of pizza (ex. cheese, sauce, salami).
Table Item_has_Menu will connect that two tables with foreign key.

My question is how can I add rows with Sql command to looks like example this:

Menu  table

```
      id_menu   name      price
        1       pizza1    5.00
        2       pizza2    6.00
```

Item table

```
      id_item  name_item  price
        1       cheese    1.00
        2       sauce     0.80
        3       salami    0.90
```

Item_has_menu table

```
               Item_Id_Item     Menu_id_Menu
                   1                1
                   2                1
                   2                2
                   3                2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use multiple insert statements.  I'll only do the first set of records, the rest are left as an exercise to the reader.

1. Create the menu by inserting into the `Menu` table.

   ```
   INSERT INTO Menu (id_menu, name, price) VALUES (1, 'pizza1', 5.00);
   ```
2. Create the item by inserting into the `Item` table.

   ```
   INSERT INTO Item (id_item, name_item, price) VALUES (1, 'cheese', 1.00);
   ```
3. Associate the two records by adding a record to the cross-reference table.

   ```
   INSERT INTO Item_has_menu (Item_id_item, Menu_id_menu) VALUES (1, 1);
   ```